# Div toggled onKeyup and stays visible Javascript and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, onkeyup

here is my problem :

I am currently designing a JavaScript function destined to verify the safety level of a password. Once the password is typed, I use jQuery to toggle the display of a div (which is invisible by default) which contains the sentence "Your password is" + the given level of safety.

Everything works fine, except that I use the `onKeyUp event` in the password-input to trigger my div appearing. However, naturally, every key pressed toggles the visibility of my div. Result: with every first key pressed in the password input, my div appears, with the next key pressed, it disappears again. Is there a way to toggle the div once with the first key pressed and prevent it from disappearing with pressing of the next key ?

Here is the code :

```
function password1Security()

{
    var pwd1 = document.getElementById("password1");
    var strongRegex = new RegExp("^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W).*$", "g");
    var mediumRegex = new RegExp("^(?=.{7,})(((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]))).*$", "g");
    var pwdsft = document.getElementById("passwordSafetyLevel1");
    {
        if (strongRegex.test(pwd1.value))
        {
            pwdsft.innerHTML = '<span style="color:green;">Safe</span>'
        } 
        else if (mediumRegex.test(pwd1.value)) 
        {
            pwdsft.innerHTML = '<span style="color:orange;">Quite Safe</span>'
        } 
        else 
        {
            pwdsft.innerHTML = '<span style="color:red;">Unsafe</span>'
        };
    }
};

<input name="password1" 
        id="password1" 
        type="password" 
        size="15" 
        maxlength="20" 
        style="width:500px; height:30px;" 
        onKeyUp="showPassSafety1()" />
<br/>
<span name="passwordSafety1" 
        id="passwordSafety1" 
        style="font-size:12pt; display:none;">Your password is <b name="passwordSafetyLevel1" id="passwordSafetyLevel1"></b>.
< /span>
<br/>
```

Comment: Code indentation is your friend :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `.one()` event handler. 
http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick response. I am a novice in jQuery and I have trouble figuring out how to write the code with the one() method. Would it be something like $("password1").one("onKeyUp",showPassSafety1()); ?

Comment: It should be `$("#password1").one("keyup",showPassSafety1());`, where `password1` is the element where the user enters password, and `showPassSafety1()` is your function to show the invisible element. Don't forget, you must use jQuery selectors - it's not `$("password1")`, but `$("#password1")`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are setting somewhere the visibility of your `passwordSafety1` span.

When you do that you should check the `length` of your `document.getElementById("password1").value` and set it visible or not depending on this length for instance; avoid switching between none and block.